# How to display custom properties from ApplicationUser in view in asp.net mvc 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I added custom properties to ApplicationUser like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Skype { get; set; }
        public string About { get; set; }
        public Photo Avatar { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to display all users with their custom properties in view. I used this  [tutorial](http://www.peter.lugt.eu/2014/11/manage-users-with-aspnet-mvc5-identity.html). But Index view works with only properties from IdentityUser.

How to get access to custom properties in Index view?

Comment: You're using `@model ApplicationUser` right?

Comment: Yes. And after that I got error - "500 - Internal server error".

Comment: You want to access those information this way: `User.Identity.Avatar()`?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is in your controller pass the ApplicationUser to the view

`return view(applicationUser)`

However what you should do is create a new view model which is simply a class like so

```
public class ApplicationUserViewModel : ApplicationUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Skype { get; set; }
        public string About { get; set; }
        public Photo Avatar { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in your controller you would populate the new ApplicationUserViewModel and then pass that into your view.

Just make sure in your View it is expecting the correct ViewModel

`@model ApplicationUserViewModel` example

Comment: Don't inherit `ApplicationUser` from the view model. Use a map instead. If you're going to do it this way, don't bother including fields for all the stuff you already have access to in the domain model.